# Installing xorg-dev

Tags: xorg

```
debjit@devilsadvocate:~/software/heasoft-6.18/BUILD_DIR$ sudo apt-get  install xorg-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xorg-dev : Depends: libxrandr-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: xserver-xorg-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Do `sudo apt -f install && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and see if it helps.

Comment: Open Software & Updates > Updates tab & make sure the 1st. two are enabled. (xenial-security & xenial-updates) Then reload sources & try again

Comment: It still shows the same problem. :(

Comment: You should leave those 2 repos enabled, there is no good reason to remove/disable as most updates are security related.